# Multiple column concatenation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to concatenate multiple columns in to a single row? For example:

```
id   name    car
1    sam     dodge
1    ram     maserati
1    john    benz
1    NULL    mazda
2    kirk    lexus
2    Jim     rolls
1            GMC
```

The expected result set is:

```
ID  name               car
1   sam,ram,john       dodge,maserati,benz,mazda,GMC
2   kirk,jim           lexus,rolls
```

Using a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749041/row-concatenation-with-for-xml-but-with-multiple-columns) I found on Stack Overflow:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT t.id,stuff([m].query('/name').value('/', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS [SomeField_Combined1],
stuff([m].query('/car').value('/', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS [SomeField_Combined2]
FROM dbo.test t
OUTER apply(SELECT (

SELECT id, ','+name AS name
,','+car AS car
FROM test WHERE test.id=t.id
FOR XML PATH('') ,type)
             AS  M) A)S
GROUP BY id,somefield_combined1,somefield_combined2
```

Are there any better solutions? The inner select comes from an expensive multi-table join (not the single table 'test' shown above). The query is in an in-line TVF, so I cannot use a temporary table.

Also, if there is a blank column the results will yield extra commas
like

```
ID  name                car
1   sam,ram,john,,      dodge,maserati,benz,mazda,GMC
2   kirk,jim           lexus,rolls
```

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran a few tests using a little over 6 mil rows.  With an index on the ID column.

Here is what I came up with.

Your initial query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.id,
            stuff([M].query('/name').value('/', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS [SomeField_Combined1],
            stuff([M].query('/car').value('/', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS [SomeField_Combined2]
    FROM dbo.test t
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT (
                    SELECT id, ','+name AS name
                    ,','+car AS car
                    FROM test WHERE test.id=t.id
                    FOR XML PATH('') ,type)
                 AS  M) 
            M ) S
GROUP BY id, SomeField_Combined1, SomeField_Combined2
```

This one ran for ~23 minutes.

I ran this version which is the version I first learned.  In some ways it seems like it should take longer but it doesn't.

```
SELECT test.id,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ThisTable.name
            FROM   test ThisTable
            WHERE  test.id = ThisTable.id
            AND    ThisTable.name <> ''
            FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') AS ConcatenatedSomeField,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + car
            FROM   test ThisTable
            WHERE  test.id = ThisTable.id
            AND    ThisTable.car <> ''
            FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') AS ConcatenatedSomeField2
FROM test 
GROUP BY id
```

This version ran in just over 2 minutes.

Comment: same here parsing the xml is too costly. What i did is I put the expensive  query in a cte and did the the same you did

Answer (score 6):

A CLR aggregate will almost certainly be the fastest way of doing this. But perhaps you don't want to use one for whatever reason...

You say that the source for this is an expensive query.

I would materialise this into a `#temp` table first to ensure it is only evaluated once.

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
ID INT,
name NVARCHAR(128),
car  NVARCHAR(128)
);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix ON #test(ID);
```

The execution plan I get for the query in the question first does the concatenation for every row in the outer query and then removes the duplicates by `id, SomeField_Combined1, SomeField_Combined2`.

This is incredibly wasteful. The following rewrite avoids this.

```
SELECT t.id,
       stuff([M].query('/name').value('/', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS [SomeField_Combined1],
       stuff([M].query('/car').value('/', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')  AS [SomeField_Combined2]
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT id
        FROM   #test) t
       OUTER APPLY(SELECT (SELECT id,
                                  ',' + name AS name,
                                  ',' + car  AS car
                           FROM   #test
                           WHERE  #test.id = t.id
                           FOR XML PATH(''), type) AS M) M
```

However for the following test data (1000 ids with 2156 rows per id for me)

```
INSERT INTO #test
SELECT v.number, o.name, o.type_desc
FROM   sys.all_objects o
       INNER JOIN master..spt_values v
         ON v.type = 'P' AND v.number BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
```

I still found Kenneth's solution with two `XML PATH` calls much faster and less resource intensive.

```
+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
|                 | CPU Time (Seconds) | Elapsed Time (Seconds) | #test Scan Count | #test Logical Reads | Worktable logical reads | Worktable lob logical reads |
+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Single XML PATH | 51.077             | 15.521                 | 1,005            | 60,165              | 51,161                  | 1,329,207                   |
| Double XML PATH | 3.1720             | 3.010                  | 2,005            | 92,088              | 14,951                  |   233,681                   |
+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

For each distinct `id` in `#test` it performs two operations instead of one but this operation is significantly cheaper than constructing the XML and then reparsing it.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by Martin Smith, a CLR aggregate is probably your best bet. Again, storing your results in a temporary table is a good idea.

Here is another possible T-SQL implementation which uses UNPIVOT/PIVOT:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #test;

CREATE TABLE #test (
    id int,
    name varchar(128),
    car varchar(128)
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix ON #test(ID);

INSERT INTO #test
SELECT v.number, o.name, o.type_desc
FROM   sys.all_objects o
       INNER JOIN master..spt_values v
         ON v.type = 'P' AND v.number BETWEEN 1 AND 1000 

;WITH info(col) AS (
    SELECT 'car'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'name'
)
SELECT *
FROM info
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id
    FROM #test
) AS ids
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT v = STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + value AS [text()]
        FROM #test
        UNPIVOT (value FOR col IN (name,car)) AS u
        WHERE col = info.col
            AND id = ids.id
            AND value <> ''
        FOR XML PATH(''), type
    ).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,SPACE(0))
) AS ca(val)
PIVOT (MIN(val) FOR col IN (car,name)) AS p;
```

It runs in approximately the same time as Kenneth's solution.

Comment: Yes I had a look into that in your blog http://spaghettidba.com/2011/10/13/concatenating-multiple-columns-across-rows/ but was  a bit difficult to understand not your fault but mine( I am bit weak in pivot and unpivot). My next task is to understand how you did that using pivot and unpivot :)

Comment: If you need help with that, drop me an email and I'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use `Right` function to remove the *leading comma* instead of `xml` functions

Use `case` statements to avoid comma for blank spaces

```
SELECT t.id, 
       RIGHT(A.NAME, Len(A.NAME) - 1) AS NAME, 
       RIGHT(A.car, Len(A.car) - 1)   AS car 
FROM   dbo.test t 
       OUTER apply(SELECT (SELECT id, 
                                  CASE WHEN NAME<>'' THEN ',' ELSE '' END + NAME  AS NAME, 
                                  CASE WHEN car<>'' THEN ',' ELSE '' END + car AS car 
                           FROM   test 
                           WHERE  test.id = t.id 
                           FOR xml path(''), type) AS M) A 
GROUP  BY id, 
          RIGHT(A.NAME, Len(A.NAME) - 1), 
          RIGHT(A.car, Len(A.car) - 1)
```

**Note:** Here `Group by` can be replaced by `distinct` as well since we are not using any `aggregate` functions